# Read-only wx.TextCtrl not appearing in tab order of wx.lib.sized_controls.SizedDialog

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm creating a subclass of wx.lib.sized_controls.SizedDialog containing some TextCtrls and a standard button sizer, but for some reason, any control that has the wx.TE_READONLY style flag set doesn't appear to be a part of the tab order inside the dialog. I can set focus to such a control by clicking on it or using its associated mnemonic, but as soon as I tab away from it, I can't tab back.

The code below demonstrates the problem. First, notice that you can tab to the editable field, type some text, and it then appears in the second, which is set to be read-only. You can press Alt+N to jump keyboard focus to the read-only control, but otherwise, you cannot set focus to it using the keyboard.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.sized_controls as sc

class SampleDialog(sc.SizedDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SampleDialog, self).__init__(None, -1, 'A Sample Dialog', style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Centre()
        self.panel = self.GetContentsPane()
        self.panel.SetSizerType('form')
        self.setup_layout()

    def create_field(self, label=None, text=None, read_only=True):
        control_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=label)
        control = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, text)
        control.SetSizerProps(expand=True)

        if read_only:
            control.SetWindowStyle(wx.TE_READONLY)

        return control

    def setup_layout(self):
        self.editable_field = self.create_field('&Editable field: ', '', read_only=False)
        self.non_editable_field = self.create_field('&Non-editable field: ', '', read_only=True)
        self.editable_field.SetFocus()
        self.editable_field.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.onTextChange)

        button_sizer = self.CreateButtonSizer(wx.OK)
        self.SetButtonSizer(button_sizer)

    def onTextChange(self, event):
        self.non_editable_field.SetValue(self.editable_field.GetValue())
        event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
sample_dialog = SampleDialog()
sample_dialog.ShowModal()
sample_dialog.Destroy()
app.MainLoop()
```

OS: Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit

Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit
(Intel)] on win32

wxPython (Phoenix) 3.0.3.dev1830+0b5f910

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that behavior before. I don't know why this is, but I solved the problem, either by using:

```
te = wx.TexTCtrl(...)
te.SetEditable(0)
```

And you do not use the READ_ONLY flag. This way your control doesn't have a read only style, but it is still read only.

Or I solved it using EVT_CHAR or some other keyboard event ton previous and last elements to  set the focus to the right element when tab is hit, or shift+tab, of course.
I used this method mostly when not using sizers, because, well, then it doesn't matter whether it is read-only or not, Keyboard focus is not automatically processed.

Pay attention when will you set the editable to False. Do it after registering the sizer.

Comment: If I use SetEditable(0), the problem still occurs here.

Comment: Odd! Did you use it after registering the sizer?

Comment: And, your read-only control is not in a sizer anyway, it is alone. When no sizers, no auto KBD focus. I don't know why wx went for that policy, but makes some sense from the point of easier implementation. So, put all inside a sizerBox.

Comment: I'm using one of the sized controls, which supposedly adds controls to the dialog's sizer whenever a child is added, so it doesn't need to be done manually.

Comment: If this is so, check whether you have to call self.Set"Something"(...) in order to make the inherited sizer active. Use help() to see the __doc__ string, wx is super coolly documented. Or just dump this and do it with normal dialog and introduce your sizers manually. It won't kill you, I promise.

Comment: Perhaps the sizer within automatic sizer is a problem. This is wild guess, but try removing the button sizer. Does then stuff work as supposed? I think that my ideas are at the end, so I don't know whether I'll be able to help you. I'll do my best though.

Comment: If I get rid of the ButtonSizer, the tab order works as expected.  Maybe I should drop the buttons in their own panel?

Comment: Yes, try their own panel or SashLayoutWindow().

Comment: I "fixed" (in inverted commas) the issue by adding the wx.TE_MULTILINE style flag and hiding the vertical scroll bar.  I'm sure there is a case for filing this as a bug, or fixing it in a way which doesn't taste quite as much like a compromise, but it'll have to wait.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Hm, why would multiline work while "single line" wouldn't? Really sounds like a bug. In your "fix" you left the button sizer in, of course?! I don't have new wxPython here, so I cannot check the wx.sized_controls code, but I'll do it when I catch the occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but figured I'd pipe in with a solution to the issue. While this still isn't fixed in wxpython 4.0.3, overwrite the AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard method of wx.TextCtrl.

```
control.AcceptsFocusFromKeyboard=lambda:True
```